# How to insert XML using XML::Writer perl

Tags: xml, perl

Im trying to make a system that can dynamically create xml based on what is entered. I have a seleton that will always be the same, and the only thing that need to be created dynamically is the formfields. So for example, I need to insert $testXML into my $writer XML. Here is what I have so far

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Writer;
my $test = XML::Writer->new(OUTPUT => 'self', DATA_MODE => 1, DATA_INDENT => 2, );
$test->startTag('FormField', name => 'CheckBox1');
$test->startTag('Value');
$test->characters('');
$test->endTag('Value');
$test->endTag('FormField');
my $testXML = $test->end();
```

Inserted into

```
my $writer = XML::Writer->new(OUTPUT => 'self', DATA_MODE => 1,           DATA_INDENT => 2, );
$writer->startTag('Section', name => 'FormSectionOne');
$writer->startTag('FormField', name => 'Person1');
$writer->startTag('Value');
$writer->characters('Bob Test');
$writer->endTag('Value');
$writer->endTag('FormField');
$testXML;
my $xml = $writer->end();
print $xml;
```

Now using $writer->raw($testXML); inserts but the formatting has problems

```
 <Section name="FormSectionOne">
      <FormField name="Person1">
        <Value>Bob Test</Value>
      </FormField><FormField name="CheckBox1">
  <Value>test</Value>
```

Comment: Please clarify. Is this two separate programs, or two parts of the same program. Please show the output that you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my $writer = XML::Writer->new(
   OUTPUT      => 'self',
   DATA_MODE   => 1,
   DATA_INDENT => 2,
   UNSAFE      => 1,
);

...
$writer->raw($testXML);
...
```

Comment: Im getting error "raw() is only available when UNSAFE is set at ./xmltest.pl line 139."

Comment: @jreed21, That means you need to pass `UNSAFE => 1` to the constructor.

Comment: Ah ok, that seems to insert it but the formatting is off                         <Section name="FormSectionOne">
          <FormField name="Person1">
            <Value>Bob Test</Value>
          </FormField><FormField name="CheckBox1">
  <Value>test</Value>
</FormField>

        </Section>

Comment: Well yeah, `$test` has no idea the XML needs extra indenting.

Comment: How would I tell it that?

Comment: You can't.  You could indent it yourself, but you're just digging the hole deeper and deeper.